# webdev:what to start with?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'd like to study webdev myself, as there is no courses like that in Russia. To say more clearly - I'd like webdev to be my profession, but i still don't how to start it. I have a lot of time, great motivation and I want to work.

So please, could you make some kind of "guide" for me (what to read, what to do) to become a really good webdeveloper. BTW, I can make some tasks for you, that are routines for you

Answer (score 1):

If you already know HTML and CSS, but need practice, one thing you can do is choose a website and recreate it using your own markup. You can either grab the existing images, or you can cut up a screenshot if you don't like how the original developer cut his/her images.

It's difficult to come up with your own practice projects if you're not a designer--I've been there myself--and using an existing site design works well for practice. And if you pick a complex site, you'll really push yourself into new areas, as you'll probably have to learn Javascript and/or how to use a Javascript library (mootools, JQuery) in order to duplicate the original functions.

I also strongly recommend learning a server-side language as recommended already.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much you know, but if you are totally green, I would recommend taking a look at the guides on http://www.w3schools.com/. Focus on html for starters.

The Head First books are also a great start I think (http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml/), but some find these books a bit too strange.

From there you probably need to learn some JavaScript (again the W3C page), and then some server side language like PHP, ASP.NET or something.

But you should start learning html and take it from there

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best way to learn Web Development is, "Learning by Doing". 
You must also understand that there are two things : Web Designing , Web Development.

I assume you want to learn Web Development.

First you select the technologies you want to be into (.NET, ASP.NET, Ruby or whatever)
Then, pick a book like "Beginning PHP5 Apache And MySQL Web Development (by Wrox)", and go through it page by page, and also try each & every example they give during the course.

After you complete one book, I guarantee you will be much more confident as you are now.

And its also good to follow a some blog you like, which publishes some todo's or something like that.

Thanks, Akshat